# Is (int)$var same as intval($var)?

Tags: php, variables, casting, integer

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Fastest way to convert string to integer in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239136/fastest-way-to-convert-string-to-integer-in-php)
>   [PHP: Is there any particular difference between intval and (int)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912599/php-is-there-any-particular-difference-between-intval-and-int)

Is `(int)$var` same as `intval($var)` ?

Apparently they both do the same thing.

Is there any situation in which they would return different results?

Comment: thanks, so (int) is waaaaay faster apparently. Now I'm going to search and replace all my code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(int)` would seem to be a bit faster than [`intval`](http://php.net/intval), as you don't have the overhead of a function call. `intval` also allows you to set an optional base to convert to, which might be useful:

```
int intval ( mixed $var [, int $base = 10 ] )
```

Comment: Yes, but is it the same? (as per the question title?)

Comment: @Jared Yes, unless the optional base parameter is something other than 10.

Comment: @Jared "The same" is fairly ambiguous/subjective.

Comment: @Jared Now I'm thinking you were just making fun of the question in the first place!

Comment: @dkamins - No, I actually wanted the documentation in the answer to exactly answer the question, thinking of those who would come after and find this in a search.