# What does (int) $_GET['page'] mean in PHP?

Tags: php, int

I tried looking up `(int)` but could only find documentation for the function `int()` in the PHP manual.

Could someone explain to me what the above code does, and exactly how it works?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It convert (tries at least) whatever the value of the variable is to a integer. If there are any letter etc, in front it will convert to a 0.

```
<?php

$var = '1a';

echo $var;               // 1a
echo (int) $var;     //1

$var2 = 'a2';
echo $var2;           //a2
echo (int) $var2;     // 0
```

?>

Answer (score 22):

You can find it in the manual in the section [type juggling: type casting](http://php.net/language.types.type-juggling#language.types.typecasting). `(int)` casts a value to int and is a language construct, which is the reason that it looks "funny".

Answer (score 4):

Simple example will make you understand:

```
var_dump((int)8);
var_dump((int)"8");
var_dump((int)"6a6");

var_dump((int)"a6");

var_dump((int)8.9);
var_dump((int)"8.9");
var_dump((int)"6.4a6");
```

Result:

```
int(8)
int(8)
int(6)

int(0)

int(8)
int(8)
int(6)
```

Answer (score 3):

`(int)` converts a value to an integer.

```
<?php
$test = "1";
echo gettype((int)$test);
?>

$ php test.php
integer
```

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, `(int)` will cast the value following it to an `int`.

Example:

```
php > var_dump((int) "5");
int(5)
```

I believe the syntax was borrowed from C.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking at there is known as **type casting** - for more information, see the manual page on [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

The above piece of code casts (or converts) `$_GET['page']` to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

it casts the variable following it to integer. more info from documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

> Type casting in PHP works much as it does in C: the name of the
> desired type is written in parentheses before the variable which is to
> be cast.
>
> The casts allowed are:
>
> - (int), (integer) - cast to integer
> - (bool), (boolean) - cast to boolean
> - (float), (double), (real) - cast to float
> - (string) - cast to string
> - (array) - cast to array (object) - cast to object
> - (unset) - cast to NULL

Answer (score 1):

this kind of syntax `(int)` is called type casting. Basically it takes the variable following it and tries to force it into being an `int`

Answer (score 1):

(int) is same as int()

see 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Comment: This is not entirely true: `(int)` is a type cast (see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) while `int()` doesn't even exist. I think you're refering to `intval()` which itself is a function and thus takes a little bit longer to execute than the type cast and offers the ability to provide a base of conversion. There are other differences discussed in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912599/is-there-any-particular-difference-between-intval-and-casting-to-int-int-x.