# PHP PDO prepared delete. Why does this fail?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I've got a small bit of code that I'm trying to execute via an ajax response. I've got the ID passing, but for some reason my delete statement fails(doesn't delete record, hence add to $err array). I'm sure it is something stupid, but it isn't jumping out at me right now.

PHP CODE

```
<?php
define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);

require '../../connect.php';
require '../../functions.php';
// Those two files can be included only if INCLUDE_CHECK is defined
// sets site to require https
echo redirectToHTTPS();
session_name('tzLogin');
session_set_cookie_params(2*7*24*60*60);
session_start();



if (isset($_POST['id']) && $_SESSION['id'] && $_SESSION['permlvl']==3 )
{
    $id = is_numeric($_POST['id']);
    $err = array();
            $query = "DELETE FROM employees WHERE id = :id";
            $statement = $db -> prepare($query);
            $statement -> BindParam('id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $result = $statement -> execute();
            $statement -> closecursor();
            if ($result === true){
            }
                else{
                    $err[] = "error";
            }
}   
//check for error messages
if(!count($err))
{
   echo 'success';
}
    else{
        //on failure, future will include logging either by sending email or writing to a log file
    }
?>
```

UPDATE
I've changed the db error mode and can get this to display. So it has to be something with how my database is designed.

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with
>   message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot
>   delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`login`.`thrives`, CONSTRAINT `thrives_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`n_emp`)
>   REFERENCES `employees` (`ID`))' in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/jen/maintabs/Employees/delete.php:23
>   Stack trace:
>   #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/jen/maintabs/Employees/delete.php(23):
>   PDOStatement->execute()
>   #1 {main}   thrown in **/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/jen/maintabs/Employees/delete.php**
>   on line **23**

Comment: What `fails` means? Only 6 lines of presented code are related to the problem, the other ones make no sense for the question

Comment: Don't do this: `$db -> prepare()`, the spaces are silly and possibly confusing. Just: `$db->prepare()`. (In general.)

Comment: The lines are related because if the prepared statement fails it adds to the $err array. If the statement executes successfully without error 'success' is passed to ajax html var.

Comment: @atrueresistance: do we need `echo redirectToHTTPS()`?? Do we need `if (isset($_POST['id']) && $_SESSION['id'] && $_SESSION['permlvl']==3 )`?? Just remove all pointless lines and give us definition of `fail`. We have no idea what you are in stuck with. This is how to handle errors with PDO: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: `Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails` --- is not it informative enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is in this line:

```
$id = is_numeric($_POST['id']);
```

`is_numeric` will return a bool. I think what you want to use something like <del>`intval`</del> `(int)$_POST['id']` instead. (Edit: @zerkms correctly points out that an explicit cast is better than `intval()`. In this case they're equivalent in functionality, but [the cast is faster.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912599/php-is-there-any-particular-difference-between-intval-and-int))

Comment: @atrueresistance - What was it about this answer that was any more attractive than deceze's? The `intval` reference?

Comment: @Jared Farrish: obviously less words to read. Reading is boring ;-)

Comment: @atrueresistance I agree with Jared. I considered deleting this answer when I saw that deceze had beaten me to the punch, but left it because I thought the `intval` thing might give some extra context.

Comment: @zerkms - deceze's is actually shorter. `:o`

Comment: @zerkms Brevity is something for which I've seldom been accused.

Comment: @AgentConundrum - No offense, I was just wondering why one upvoted answer was completely passed over for another which is nearly identical.

Comment: @AgentConundrum: actually `(int)` cast is better than `intval()`

Comment: @JaredFarrish None taken. As I said, I considered deleting the answer when I saw deceze's answer.

Comment: @zerkms Ironically, my answer was late specifically because I was debating which of the two to reference. I ultimately decided that they were equivalent in this case, but apparently `(int)` is faster, so.. yeah. Oops.

Answer (score 6):

```
$id = is_numeric($_POST['id']);

...

$statement -> BindParam('id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

`is_numeric` returns a *boolean*. The value of `$id` is `true` or `false`, not a number.

Comment: "*The value of `$id` **at this point** is `true` or `false`, not a number.*"

Comment: Sure, but since there's no other use of `$id`... :)

Comment: Yep, just my own comment. `:)`