# In PHP, why use inval() rather than casting with (int)?

Tags: php, types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any particular difference between intval and (int)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912599/is-there-any-particular-difference-between-intval-and-int)

These two statements are, afaik, identical:

```
$i = (int)getSomeValue();
```

and

```
$i = intval(getSomeValue());
```

Is there are good reason to choose one over the other (e.g. performance, treatment of nulls or objects, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In contrast to casting, [`intval`](http://php.net/intval) also allows non-decimal bases.

Additionally, every programmer knows functions and can easily look them up at `php.net/function`, whereas casts are not as widely known.