# PHP - Purpose of intval()?

Tags: php, casting

What, exactly, is the purpose of the `intval()` function for a base-10 calculation? Isn't it the exact same as a typecast, just slower? In all of my Googling, I haven't found a single benefit. What am I missing?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912599/is-there-any-particular-difference-between-intval-and-int (not quite a duplicate)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`intval()` lets you specify a base to convert from.

```
$decimal_value = intval("FF", 16)
```

For simple base-10 conversions, there's no reason to use `intval()`.

Comment: If you constrain your question like that, then yes, there's no reason to use `intval()`... but that's kind of like asking "what's the point `preg_replace()` if I'm just doing basic string replacement, it's like `str_replace()` but slower".

Answer (score 1):

`intval()` can accept a base parameter, casting to an int cannot.

Comment: Yeah, I've modified my question. Sorry about that.