# How do I truncate a decimal in PHP?

Tags: php, truncate

I know of the PHP function `floor()` but that doesn't work how I want it to in negative numbers.

**This is how floor works**

```
floor( 1234.567); //  1234
floor(-1234.567); // -1235
```

**This is what I WANT**

```
truncate( 1234.567); //  1234
truncate(-1234.567); // -1234
```

Is there a PHP function that will return -1234?

I know I could do this but I'm hoping for a single built-in function

```
$num = -1234.567;
echo $num >= 0 ? floor($num) : ceil($num);
```

Comment: I don't think there is one... why bother about that few characters? The intention of your line is quite clear.

Comment: `number_format($num, 0, '', '');`?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I just tried the number_format way and it actually returns -1235 like the `floor()` function does. Strange!

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the single-line solution you mentioned?  Of course, you could wrap that into a function if that were your goal, but testing for whether floor or ceiling is the correct operation based on sign is the appropriate approach based on PHP's definition of available math functions.

Comment: @chrislondon  It is better to use (int) typecast. See my answer.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy number_format rounds, it doesn't truncate

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

```
intval(1234.567);
intval(-1234.567);
```

Comment: I like this because `intval` is indicative of what I'm really trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 11):

Truncate floats with specific precision:

```
echo bcdiv(2.56789, 1, 1);  // 2.5
echo bcdiv(2.56789, 1, 3);  // 2.567
echo bcdiv(-2.56789, 1, 1); // -2.5
echo bcdiv(-2.56789, 1, 3); // -2.567
```

This method solve the problem with `round()` function.

Comment: This is good if you have the library to open, otherwise you'll get a fatal error: "Call to undefined function bcdiv()"

Answer (score 4):

Also you can use typecasting (no need to use functions),

```
(int) 1234.567; //  1234
(int) -1234.567; // -1234
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

You can see the difference between `intval` and `(int)` typecasting from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912599/is-there-any-particular-difference-between-intval-and-int).

Comment: That's not what he wants though. Both lines should be 1234 in his example.

Comment: @Rich Bradshaw Sry.. it's my mistake. I just copied the first code block and forgot to edit the commented part. Live demo here http://codepad.org/7gBgAHBK

Comment: I wish I could mark two answers as correct. I like both `intval()` and `(int)`

Comment: @chrislondon That's ok :). But you should check this https://wiki.phpbb.com/Best_Practices:PHP#Typecasting

Comment: I'd typically use these functions rather than intval.

Answer (score 2):

another hack is using prefix `~~` :

```php
echo ~~1234.567; // 1234
echo ~~-1234.567; // 1234
```

it's simpler and faster

Tilde `~` is bitwise NOT operator in PHP and Javascript

Double tilde(`~`) is a quick way to cast variable as integer, where it is called 'two tildes' to indicate a form of double negation.

It removes everything after the decimal point because the bitwise operators implicitly convert their operands to signed 32-bit integers. This works whether the operands are (floating-point) numbers or strings, and the result is a number

reference:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_tilde
- [What does ~~ ("double tilde") do in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055633/what-does-double-tilde-do-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

you can use intval(number); but if your number bigger than 2147483648 (and your machine/os is x64) all bigs will be truncated to 2147483648. So you can use

```
if($number < 0 )
$res = round($number);
else
$res = floor($number); 

echo $res;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shift the decimal to the desired place, intval, and shift back:

```
function truncate($number, $precision = 0) {
   // warning: precision is limited by the size of the int type
   $shift = pow(10, $precision);
   return intval($number * $shift)/$shift;
}
```

**Note the warning about size of int** -- this is because `$number` is potentially being multiplied by a large number (`$shift`) which could make the resulting number too large to be stored as an integer type. Possibly converting to floating point might be better.

You could get fancy with a `$base` parameter, and sending that to `intval(...)`.

Could (should) also get fancy with error/bounds checking.

**An alternative approach** would be to treat number as a string, find the decimal point and do a substring at the appropriate place after the decimal based on the desired precision. Relatively speaking, that won't be fast.