# PHP (int) on Compound Statements

Tags: php, int

This caught me by surprise. The code

```
$strA = '1234';
$strB = '56';
$cast = (int) $strA.$strB;
var_dump($cast);
```

outputs: string(6) "123456"

I was expecting $cast to be an integer. This behavior might cause a security hole if someone were putting together strings from $_POST. The code

```
$strA = '1234';
$strB = '56-SQL Injection';
$cast = (int) $strA.$strB;
```

outputs: string(20) "123456-SQL Injection"

If $strB were from an external source like $_POST; the script might be open to an injection attack.

I've been reading posts like the [difference between (int) and intval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912599/is-there-any-particular-difference-between-intval-and-casting-to-int-int-x) trying to find out where this full behavior of (int) is documented.

So my question is: I was expecting "(int) $strA.$strB" to be an integer. Why is it still a string and where is this behavior documented?

Comment: parentheses! `(int) "abc"."def"` is not the same as `(int) ("abc"."def")`, but the same as `((int) "abc")."def"` - oh, and by the way: to prevent SQL Injection, use **parameterized statements only!**

Comment: Exactly - operator precendence: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: @FranzGleichmann you can definitely write an answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour is caused by operator precedence, see also the corresponding [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

basically:

```
(int) $a.$b;
```

is not the same as

```
(int) ($a.$b); //which is the one you want
```

but the same as

```
((int) $a).$b;
```

which in your case casts $a to an int, which is valid, which then is implicitely cast back to string to concatenate with $b.
(for non-numeric strings, for example `$a="b"`, this would result in the final string `"0456"`)

see this example output:

```
<?php
$a = "123";
$b = "456";
$c = (int) $a.$b;
$d = (int) ($a.$b);
$e = ((int) $a).$b;
var_dump($c, $d, $e);
```

> string '123456' (length=6)
>   int 123456
>   string '123456' (length=6)

Also: unless you absolutely *can not*, always use **parameterized statements** to prevent SQL Injection - they are as close to foolproof as possible.

Comment: Thanks. I admit I had pretty much figured out the answer before asking the question. (int) behaves like an operator. It has an unexpectedly high order of precedence.